# How to append conditional data to the end of the JSON

Tags: php, laravel

I am iterating over a model relationship

```
$formatted = [];
foreach($products->childProducts as $childProduct) {
        if($childProduct->product_type_id > 1) {
           $formatted['associated_products'][] = $this->coreProductInfo($childProduct);
       }
    }
```

There is a condition `$childProduct->product_type_id` which when == 1, those products should not be appended to the array above. Instead all those product(s) with product_type_id == 1 should be appended at the last when the above array is fully prepared. i.e when product_type_id: 2,3,4... all have been already  appended.

How can I achieve this so that all products with type id 1 should get appended to the end?

The expected result:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "product_name": "Shirts",
    "product_category": "Men Garments",
    "product_area": "Western",
    "product_region": "Mumbai",
    "product_type_id": "2",
    "product_uuid": "398jehiu3939e3393"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "product_name": "Trousers",
    "product_category": "Men Garments",
    "product_area": "Eastern",
    "product_region": "Mumbai",
    "product_type_id": "3",
    "product_uuid": "dnnja3989389834343"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "product_name": "Jeggings",
    "product_category": "Women Garments",
    "product_area": "Western",
    "product_region": "Delhi",
    "product_type_id": "1",
    "product_uuid": "ji202039844930300dj"
}
```

]

Comment: store them in two seperate arrays, merge them after looping ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best use collection..

```
    $formatted = collect();
    foreach($products->childProducts as $childProduct) {
        if($childProduct->product_type_id > 1) {
            $formatted->prepend($this->coreProductInfo($childProduct));
        } else {
            $formatted->push($this->coreProductInfo($childProduct));
        }
    }
    $formatted->toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Svetoslav. Worked like a charm!